# nodejs mongoose connect to db error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've created a db.js and empleado.js in model folder. I can connect to db.js, but not to the empleado.js. I'm export that connection in empleado.js but the console display the following error:

```
$ node app
C:\Users\Dario\documents\02 - trabajo\97 - proyectos\test\app.js:14
empleado.setConnection(db);
         ^

TypeError: empleado.setConnection is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Dario\documents\02 - trabajo\97 - proyectos\
test\app.js:14:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:565:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:3)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var routes = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');


var db = require('./model/db');               // DataBase Connection
var empleado = require('./model/empleado');   // Employee Data Model
empleado.setConnection(db);

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');                     // Utilizo Jade para vas views (vistas)

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));  // Activamos un directorio de archivos estáticos

app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handlers

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.render('error', {
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error', {
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});

module.exports = app;
```

**db.js**

```
// Integro mongoose al proyecto
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Archivo de configuración de la Base de Datos
var config = require('../config/db');

// Armo el string de conección de la Base de Datos
var dbURI = 'mongodb://' + config.host + '/' + config.db;

// Conecto la Base de Datos
var db = mongoose.connect(dbURI);

// Gestionando eventos de conección a la Base de Datos
db.connection.on('connected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose conectado a ' + dbURI);
});

db.connection.on('error',function (err) {
    console.log('Mongoose error de conección: ' + err);
});

db.connection.on('disconnected', function () {
    console.log('Mongoose desconectado');
});

process.on('SIGINT', function() {
    db.connection.close(function () {
        console.log('Mongoose desconectado por finalización de la aplicación');
        process.exit(0);
    });
});

module.exports = db;
```

**empleado.js**

```
   var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    exports.setConnection = function(connection) {
        mongoose = connection;
    }


    var empSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
        nombre: String,
        apellidos: String
    });

    var empModelo = mongoose.model('Empleado', empSchema, 'empleados');

    module.exports = empModelo;
```

Thanks in advance.
I'm new in mongoDB, Mongoose and NodeJS

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach here would be passing mongoose when requiring `empleado.js`:

```
var empleado = require('./model/empleado')(mongoose);
```

Then you don't need to have a setConnection method.

Your `empleado.js` file would be like:

```
module.exports = function(mongoose) {
   var empSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
    nombre: String,
    apellidos: String
   });

   return mongoose.model('Empleado', empSchema, 'empleados');
};
```

Comment: the connection was exported to empleado.js, but the collection 'empleados' is not shown in the connection

Comment: Can you please elaborate? Have you tried saving a or getting a document using the model? Has the crash been fixed?